# Anchors based tab navigation jquery code not working

Tags: jquery

```
var url = document.location.toString();
        if (url.match('#')) { // the URL contains an anchor
          // click the navigation item corresponding to the anchor
          var myAnchor = '#' + url.split('#')[1];
          $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
          $("ul.tabs li a:" + myAnchor).addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
          $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
          $(myAnchor).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active ID content
        }
```

Why is the "li" element not being made active

Try accessing => http://domainsoutlook.com/s/site/stackoverflow.com.html#meta_info

[image]

Comment: Works for me.  Can you post some of the html you have?

Comment: It is, at least in Chrome/OS X.

Comment: If you post the HTML, just post it on jsfiddle.net; much easier.

Comment: Why not use `window.location.hash` instead of splitting the URL.

Comment: the first time you access the webpage and open it with the anchor tag, none of the tabs are shown to be active. The content for the tab is being shown. Try clicking other tabs once the page loads and you would know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector to get the tab is off. Your selector is `"ul.tabs li a:#meta_info"`, which is not a real selector.  You want to find the a with an href of "#meta_info".  Try this instead:

```
$("ul.tabs li a[href='" + myAnchor + "']")
```

Answer (score 1):

You're adding the class to the anchor, not the li.

Try this instead:

```
$("ul.tabs li a:" + myAnchor).parent().addClass("active");
```